# Number of clusters increased with the increase of MinPts in scikit-learn DBSCAN

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I use DBSCAN implementation from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) library and I got strange results.
The number of estimated clusters increased with the increase of parameter MinPts (min_samples) and from my understanding of algorithm this should not happend.

Here are my results:

```
Estimated number of clusters:34 eps=0.9 min_samples=13.0
Estimated number of clusters:35 eps=0.9 min_samples=12.0
Estimated number of clusters:42 eps=0.9 min_samples=11.0 <- strange result here
Estimated number of clusters:37 eps=0.9 min_samples=10.0   
Estimated number of clusters:53 eps=0.9 min_samples=9.0
Estimated number of clusters:63 eps=0.9 min_samples=8.0
```

I use scikit-learn like this:

```
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
db = DBSCAN(eps=eps, min_samples=min_samples, algorithm='kd_tree').fit(X)
```

and X is an array that contains ~200k 12-dimensional points.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: You may want to have a look at OPTICS (*not* available in python. The python OPTICS implementation you find with Google is *incorrect*; essentially its DBSCAN again). It works similar to DBSCAN, but you don't have to choose epsilon. [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) has a good implementation of OPTICS, with indexing support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DBSCAN divides points/samples into three categories:

1. Core: lives in a dense neighborhood and may therefore give rise to a cluster. `min_samples` in scikit-learn's implementation is the neighborhood density parameter.
2. Density-reachable: close enough to a core point to be part of its cluster.
3. Outliers: all the rest.

Now, as you require a denser neighborhood for core points, you get fewer core points, but a core point *x* losing its status can have three effects depending on the density just outside its neighborhood:

1. *x* is still density-reachable from the core points of its former cluster and the remaining core points are able to hold the cluster together. The number of clusters is unchanged.
2. *x* is still density-reachable from at least two core points, but no longer acts as a density-connecting "bridge" between the core points, causing them to form separate clusters. The number of clusters increases and *x* is assigned to another point's cluster.
3. Neither *x*, nor its neighbor points are able to sustain their former cluster and it disappears, leaving *x* as an outlier. The number of clusters decreases.